# How to enable server side encryption on DynamoDB via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to enable encryption on my production tables in DynamoDB. According to their docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/encryption.tutorial.html#encryption.tutorial-cli I just use the `--sse-specification` flag; however, it's not working via CLI

I copied their exact command from the docs, below

```
aws dynamodb create-table \
  --table-name Music \
  --attribute-definitions \
      AttributeName=Artist,AttributeType=S \
      AttributeName=SongTitle,AttributeType=S \
  --key-schema \
      AttributeName=Artist,KeyType=HASH \
      AttributeName=SongTitle,KeyType=RANGE \
  --provisioned-throughput \
      ReadCapacityUnits=10,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
  --sse-specification Enabled=true
```

Using their exact example or any other contrived setup I keep getting the same error message when ran from CLI

> Unknown options: --sse-specification, Enabled=true

Is it possible to turn this on from CLI? The only other way I see is to create each table manually from the console and tick the encryption button during creation there

My AWS version is

> aws-cli/1.14.1 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.5.0 botocore/1.8.32

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: @KevinSeaman Pasted in original question as well, aws-cli/1.14.1 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/17.5.0 botocore/1.8.32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update your version of the CLI.  Version 1.14.1 was released on 11/29/2017, SSE on DynamoDB wasn't released until 2/8/2018.